# angularjs: changing the background-size from cover to contain

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am practicing angular and I have some pages that have a main image callled "MainImg". In CSS, it is formatted the following way:

```
.main-section__main-image{
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url({{ settings["MainImg"] }}) top no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            }
```

So using MainImg in my controller will display the image with the respective settings.

However, some of these pictures are too big or wide, and I would like to format them differently. How could I change the background-size to contain ONLY for some of the pictures? The app is data driven so the settings are applied to all of the pictures named MainImg.

Answer (score 0):

Need some more context on what your controller and possibly model look like, but here's an approach you can try.

Add a field to `MainImg` for className.  That will either contain "main-section__main-image" or it will contain "main-section__main-image main-image__cover", depending on whether or not you need to set `background-size` for the image in question.

Use the `ng-class` directive in your view to read the desired class from this field.

Move the `background-size` rule in your CSS to the new `.main-image__cover` class, and it should work.